# Import hashed password from flask to django

Tags: python, django

I have to migrate my flask Users to django. In flask I generated the password with the werkzeug lib like:

```
generate_password_hash(value, method='sha256')
```

In the django import I save the password:

```
u.password = hashed_pw
```

now the password is in the database like:

```
'sha256$VSvtvATP$2c87cf...'
```

now django can't verify my password. How can I convert the password so that django can handle it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django uses a different password hashing algorithm by default, namely PBKDF2 *with* SHA-256. The only way you could move the existing hashes over to Django would be to tell it to use a different hasher. A plain SHA-256-Hasher isn't built-in, so you'd have to [write your own](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/passwords/#writing-your-own-hasher).

---

However, I would consider not doing that and providing a migration path for your existing users, since PBKDF2-sha256 is considered more secure:

Store these hashes in an additional field on your user, and prompt them to change their password on their first login (then throw away the old hash and only save their password hashed the Django way). You *could* even do this transparently to your users (i.e. on first login, after checking the hash matches with the old hash from Flask, generate a new hash based on the same password (that you have at this point in time) and store it, then throw the old hash away.

Comment: or in a rude way, ask everyone to reset their password

Comment: how would you do this? you first need to verify that a user has the correct password, before allowing them to change it. you'd have to do this via mail at least.

Comment: The solution described above does not require to reset the password. It does not even require to force the user to change the password. It can happily run with the old hash until the user changes the password. But it might be good to push the user to some degree.

Answer (score 1):

flask and django use `hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac` to generate password hash. the difference is the format and encoding. so possible to translate the password hash from one format to another transparently. (I wonder why not uniform and decrease the friction)

```
def trans_hash(str):
        """from flask to django"""
        [alg, _hash_alg, rest] = str.split(':')
        [iteration, salt, hashed] = rest.split('$')
        # in flask hex() formated, so decode using b16decode
        # https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/main/src/werkzeug/security.py#L162
        raw_hash = base64.b16decode(hashed.strip().encode('ascii').upper())
        # in django, use b64encode, https://github.com/django/django/blob/ca9872905559026af82000e46cde6f7dedc897b6/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py#L276
        hashed = base64.b64encode(raw_hash).decode('ascii').strip()
        rest = '$'.join([iteration, salt, hashed] )
        return f"{alg}_{_hash_alg}${rest}"
```

a password hash in flask:

```
pbkdf2:sha256:150000$zwBNBm5i$be85b2739ab81c94ea2596fe79c0f6e7d211561f5ea1525c5620e817ef3ea82b
```

will translate to (django)

```
pbkdf2_sha256$150000$zwBNBm5i$voWyc5q4HJTqJZb+ecD259IRVh9eoVJcViDoF+8+qCs=
```

Comment: Can you do the same from django to flask?

Comment: @supersick just reverse the `trans_hash`

Comment: @echo2 i tried for like 1,5 days but i failed

Comment: ```def django_to_flask_hash(django_hash):
    alg, hash_alg_with_rest = django_hash.split("_", 1)

    hash_alg, iterations, rest = hash_alg_with_rest.split("$", 2)

    raw_hash = base64.b64decode(rest.strip().encode("ascii"))  
    rest = base64.b16encode(raw_hash.lower()).decode("ascii").strip()

    return f"{alg}:{hash_alg}:{iterations}${rest}" ```

Comment: @supersick this produces ` Invalid base64-encoded string: number of data characters (65) cannot be 1 more than a multiple of 4` for me? Any idea?